# How to create an instance of the class containing main method in a Spring project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm developing a console application with spring framework and I have a method in the Main class and I need to access that method by creating an instance but when I try to do so an error regarding bean is shown. 
So how to create an instance of that class correctly.

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {


@Autowired
private Repository repository;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    welcome();
}

public void welcome(){
    -----------------------------
    -----------------------------
    -----------------------------
}
}
```

Example.java

```
public class Example {

Application obj = new Application();

public void check(){
    obj.welcome();
}
}
```

As the above code shows I created the instance of the Application class in the traditional way but it won't work. It says

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:

This is my first experience with Spring so please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if you would like to get started with spring visit [spring initializr](https://start.spring.io/) and generate a project  with `Spring Web` Dependency.

Then all you need is an IDE to open up the project and that's it!

This is my main class where spring starts.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Note that  the first parameter of `SpringApplication.run` has the same name with my `.class` file.

Then i configure everything else independently and not confuse it with my `main` class

---

if you would like to build web, including RESTful, applications use  the `Spring Web`  (if you generate it from the website it will be in your `pom.xml` automatically.)  It uses Apache Tomcat as the default embedded container.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

---

Hope it helps!

Comment: I want help on creating the instance of Application class in Example class. There's a bean error on runtime when I try to execute it like that.